# meteor 1.4 react complains about unknown props

Tags: javascript, meteor, reactjs, meteor-react

I have defined a react component:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDom from 'react-dom';

export default class Silly extends React.Component {
   render() {
    return (
        <h1>{this.props.dumdum}</h1>
    );
  }
}
Silly.propTypes = {
 dumdum: React.PropTypes.string
}
```

and in client/main.jsx I try to call it:

```
//some import stuff, omitted...

Meteor.startup(() => {
ReactDom.render(<Silly dumdum="helloooo"/>, document.getElementById('app-target'));
 });
```

This gives me the following error and the component does not render:

> warning.js:36Warning: Unknown prop `dumdum` on  tag. Remove this prop from the element. For details, see https://facebook.github.io/react/warnings/unknown-prop.html

(actually the link is a shorter one, but I can't seem to be able to post it here...)

Thanks for any pointers of what could be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

OK, the problem was that I was using lower case component names (the sample above is not the real code...), so it was ..

Lower case components don't seem to be treated as react components...
https://gist.github.com/sebmarkbage/f1f4ba40816e7d7848ad

Just in case anybody comes across the same problem.